# Uniform convergence in closed segment

Tags: calculus, uniform-convergence

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{2nx+1}{n+nx^2}$. I want to prove that it is uniform converging in $[0,3]$.
The pointwise limit function is $f(x)=\frac{2x}{1+x^2}$.
I was able to find a supremun to $|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ which is $\frac {1}{n} \rightarrow 0$.
Does this prove that $f_n(x)$ converges in $[0,3]$?

Comment: I haven't checked if what you said is right, but if the supremum is indeed $\frac{1}{n}$, then yes, this is enough.

Comment: So if I'm asked about a closed segment and able to show there is a supremum that is not depending on $x$ that is tending to 0 then it's enough?

Comment: You don't even need a closed domain for that. (The supremum does never depend on $x$ btw.)

Answer (score 0):

The fact $\sup_{x\in[0,3]}|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ converges to $0$ is indeed enough, and actually equivalent to the uniform convergence on $[0,3]$. This is an instructive exercise to show it with $\varepsilon$'s.

And indeed, in your context, the supremum is equal to $1/n$ (reached at $0$).